# SQL Like operator with Percentage matching

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I am creating a search query something like this

```
select * from tbl_cities where city_name like "%du%"
```

But i have so many datas in the table city.So the processing time is too big.
Is there any way to get exact matches something like a percentage matching to minimize the array size returning and hence the processing time.

For example i have **"dubai"** and **"dubai marina"** in the table.And the query will return both.I want only **"dubai"** because it matches more percentage wise.

Comment: The `LIKE` expression either matches a record one or more times, in which case the record gets returned, or it does not match.  Please add sample data which explains what you have in mind here.

Comment: why not using full text search indexing? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html it would be better to implement it that just `like` statments.

Comment: I am using yii2 framework.I doesn't support mysql full text search

Answer (score 1):

Please try this way.

```
select * from tbl_cities where city_name like "d%i"
```

> this `d%i` Finds any values that start with "d" and ends with "i" like `dubai`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try RLIKE instead of LIKE. RLIKE is little bit faster.

```
select * from tbl_cities where city_name rlike "^du"
```